# How to add a class to an appended variable that's already calling on a container div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, append

I'm using a fetch xml to loop through an appointments database to view them on a html page:

```
if (results !=null && results.value !=null {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
    time = results.value[i].starttime;
    place = results.value[i].location;
    who = results.value[i].attendee;

    $("#homediv").append(time);
    $("#homediv").append(place);
    $("#homediv").append(who);
  }
}
```

They're all appearing successfully in the within the same div with the id of 'homediv'. However I want to add a class to each of these elements separately in order to style them differently in the css but it's not working. I tried 'addClass' but doing the following in the code:

```
$("#homediv").append(time).addClass('time-style');
$("#homediv").append(place)addClass('place-style');
$("#homediv").append(who)addClass('who-style');
```

But that simply doesn't work. Can anyone spot what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this instead

```
$("#homediv").append(`<span class='time-style'>${time}</span>`);
$("#homediv").append(`<span class='place-style'>${place}</span>`);
$("#homediv").append(`<span class='who-style'>${who}</span>`);
```

or without string interpolation (ES6)

```
$("#homediv").append("<span class='time-style'>" + time + "</span>");
$("#homediv").append("<span class='place-style'>" + place + "</span>");
$("#homediv").append("<span class='who-style'>" + who + "</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that your appended element is a div:

```js
$("#homediv").append("<div>time</div>").find("div").last().addClass('time-style');
$("#homediv").append("<div>place</div>").find("div").last().addClass('place-style');
$("#homediv").append("<div>who</div>").find("div").last().addClass('who-style');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="homediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the last() element of $("#homediv") immediately after the append() action, but you have to know the appended element tag:

```
$("#homediv").append(time);
$("#homediv").find('<time tag>').last().addClass('time-style');
```

etc.